# How can I remove code from jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a wordpress plugin installed, I want to access the code bellow in order to remove the part after: // Init prettyPhoto. Is there a way to access the code, so I can edit variables, function ? How would you do this ? Wordpress plugins get updated frequently, so whenever the plugin gets updated, any change I do would be lost.  I want to know if there is a way to edit the variables, functions, on run time, without changing the file itself.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
"use strict";

var qv_modal    = $(document).find( '#yith-quick-view-modal' ),
    qv_overlay  = qv_modal.find( '.yith-quick-view-overlay'),
    qv_content  = qv_modal.find( '#yith-quick-view-content' ),
    qv_close    = qv_modal.find( '#yith-quick-view-close' );


/*==================
 *MAIN BUTTON OPEN
 ==================*/

$.fn.yith_quick_view = function() {

    var button  = $(document).find( '.yith-wcqv-button' );

    // remove prev click event
    button.off( 'click' );

    button.on( 'click', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var t           = $(this),
            product_id  = t.data( 'product_id' ),
            is_blocked  = false;

        if ( typeof yith_qv.loader !== 'undefined' ) {
            is_blocked = true;
            t.block({
                message: null,
                overlayCSS  : {
                    background: '#fff url(' + yith_qv.loader + ') no-repeat center',
                    opacity   : 0.5,
                    cursor    : 'none'
                }
            });
        }
        ajax_call( t, product_id, is_blocked );
    });
};
.
.
.
.
.

/*================
 * MAIN AJAX CALL
 ================*/

var ajax_call = function( t, product_id, is_blocked ) {

    $.post( yith_qv.ajaxurl, { action: 'yith_load_product_quick_view', product_id: product_id }, function( data ) {

        qv_content.html( data );

        // quantity fields for WC 2.2
        if( yith_qv.is2_2 ) {
            qv_content.find('div.quantity:not(.buttons_added), td.quantity:not(.buttons_added)').addClass('buttons_added').append('<input type="button" value="+" class="plus" />').prepend('<input type="button" value="-" class="minus" />');
        }

        // Variation Form
        var form_variation = qv_content.find( '.variations_form' );

        form_variation.wc_variation_form();

        if( typeof $.fn.yith_wccl !== 'undefined' ) {
            form_variation.yith_wccl();
        }

        // Init prettyPhoto
        if( typeof $.fn.prettyPhoto !== 'undefined' ) {
            qv_content.find("a[data-rel^='prettyPhoto'], a.zoom").prettyPhoto({
                hook              : 'data-rel',
                social_tools      : false,
                theme             : 'pp_woocommerce',
                horizontal_padding: 20,
                opacity           : 0.8,
                deeplinking       : false
            });
        }

        if( ! qv_modal.hasClass( 'open' ) ) {
            qv_modal.addClass('open');
            if( is_blocked )
                t.unblock();
        }

        // stop loader
        $(document).trigger( 'qv_loader_stop' );

    });
};

});
```

Comment: Open the JavaScript file, remove the code, save it to your server?

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't explain my self very good. Wordpress plugins get updated frequently, so whenever the plugin gets updated, any change I do would be lost.  I want to know if there is a way to edit the variables, functions, on run time, without changing the file itself. Thanks for your answer though, I'll go ahead and edit my question.

Comment: If you can find out where your plugin en-queues this script, you can dequeue it, and enqueue your own, from your own plugin.

Comment: What plugin is this?

Comment: Hi George, the plugin is YITH WooCommerce Quick View

Answer (score 0):

You can just directly edit that file on your server, like any other.

Comment: I want to to do it in run time, without modifying the file. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by three following methods

1.Login to ftp and go to 
wp-content/plugins/ then  go to your plugin folder, edit file and save

2.Login to cpanel and edit file and save

3.If you dont have access to cpanel or ftp then you can try with wp admin
login to wp-admin, go to plugin editor and select plugin and file to edit, make changes and save

if you dont have access of any then please ask for details.

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't explain my self very good. I want to know if there is a way to edit the variables, functions, on run time, without changing the file itself.

Comment: you surely can change them if they are one of the options provided with prettyphoto.

Comment: here are options http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation

Comment: and if you have not called the function means it is being called by plugin then you should check plugin options in backend.

Comment: To be more precise is woocommerce fancybox, I've tried a lot of things, and narrowed the problem down to the piece of code from my example, if I remove it from the file, things work as I want to, but I don't like that approach, I want to remove/overwrite from my child theme js.